# does “all” mean “everything” in this expression?

Tags: word-usage, expressions, meaning-in-context

there’s a common British English expression:

> - If all goes to plan

in some way it seems to me that “*all goes*” doesn’t make sense, because I usually come across “all” as a plural

Comment: Yes: *all* does mean *everything.* See [Oxford sense 1.4](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/all).

Comment: 'All is well' and 'all is not lost' also use 'all' as a singular meaning 'all things'. But in elipsis, when 'things' is dropped, 'all' becomes singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic phrase uses *all* in the sense of *everything*:

> **all**
>   1.4 pronoun (used to refer to surroundings or a situation in general) everything.
>   ‘all was well’
>   ‘all is not lost yet’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/all)

It is idiomatically singular. *All* refers to a monolithic totality in this context.

If you take *all* to refer to the plurality of composites (and hence use plural agreement), you get quite a different meaning:

> **all**
>   1 Used to refer to the whole quantity or extent of a particular group or thing.
>   (as pronoun) ‘carry all of the blame’
>   ‘we all have different needs’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/all)

In that case, "if all **go** to plan" would mean something like "if all people go to do some planning".